# How to use Probability (-b1) for one-class classification using LibSVM?

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm, one-class

I need some information concerning the LibSVM one-class classification.

I use -b1 for two-class classification in SvmTrain and my outputs are prob values and prob labels. I want to use the similar way that I used for two-class classification but for one class classification but LibSvm does not support -b1 (probability). what can I do?

Thanks